# Short story which has living mountains that move very very slowly

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I remember reading a short story decades ago whose plot involved colonisers on a planet thinking it had no life. Later they realise that the mountains are indeed alive, but move so slowly they could not realise it at that time. Does anyone know which one this is?

Comment: Thanks for the response. I read it in the late 80s, and suspect it was written sometime in the 80s. The story was pretty much that the colonisers (possibly humans, I don't recall now) realised that there was indeed life on the planet, only that this life, mountains, moved slowly over millenia. And conversely, the mountains did not therefore notice these colonisers either. I think the story pretty much ended there. Thats all I can recall, sorry! I tried searching for it online but without success.

Comment: Thanks Otis - that's pretty close, but not the one I had in mind, though.

Comment: I don't suppose it could have been one of Anne McCaffrey's stories, what you're describing sounds like it could be her alien Thek species (the larger older ones that is).

Comment: @Pelinore - no, I am afraid not ...